# Updating iOS apps automatically with an MDM + Enterprise license

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, enterprise, mdm

We have an iPad app running in a kiosk mode deployed across multiple physical locations. We'd like to have a solution where any updates to the app are pushed automatically to the device so that the client does not have to touch each iPad they have.

Our client has an existing MDM software that notifies the user if there's an update, but since it's intended to be a kiosk we don't want the general public to actually do the update by themselves.

Does anyone know if this is possible at all?

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** As of iOS 7, you can now force an app update through MDM software.

---

(Previously for iOS 6 and below):

Sorry, but with even with the enterprise program and an MDM server, you cannot force an update on an iOS device.

Your best bet would be to configure the updates so that they run automatically just by clicking once and accepting the update.  That way it is safe for anyone to accept.

Sources: Own knowledge and [this site](http://www.esecurityplanet.com/views/article.php/11163_3919161_3/Review-AirWatch-Enterprise-MDM-for-Apple-iOS4.htm).

Comment: Is this still true with ios7?

Answer (score 1):

I know that as of iOS 7, this is no longer the case. If your app is managed via your MDM solution, you can force an update.