# Update Enterprise App in the background

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

My application will be running in the background and user rarely opens the app. Hence i'm using the Enterprise distribution it will not go to app store. Is there a way to update the application when it is running in the background. When it is in the foreground it is updating fine. When i try to achieve the same in background i get a warning "LaunchServices: application launch failed with error 9" message. Any help would be appreciated. I did refer to question. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838556/can-i-update-an-ios-enterprise-app-in-the-background-like-an-app-store-app-can)